# how to find a pit in a directed graph?

Tags: java, algorithm

Question : we have a directed graph , how to find a hole (pit) in a graph on Ɵ(n) time complexity .

a pit on graph : if an vertex with n-1 degree for (input) and degree 0 for (output) , we have a pit on graph .

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far ? What does Google say ?

Comment: How can it have 0 degrees, yet be connected to another vertex ?

Comment: i searched on google but no result .

Comment: do you mean if a vertex with 0 degree, instead of edge with 0 degree?

Comment: yeah we have vertex .

Comment: I think the term for such a node is sink.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outdegree#Indegree_and_outdegree) is what OP meant

Comment: thanks @HunterMcMillen for your help , i know that .

Comment: You didn't define n. Is that the number of nodes in your graph? Also, for the time complexity to make sense you have to tell us how the graph is represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to search graph at all.
you can just count indegree and outdegree of every node. you just have to look for which node- indegree of a node is (n-1) and outdegree is '0'.

Considering you know "how many edges" are there.

```
int outdegree[n]={0}; // Storing outdegree of each node
int indegree[n]={0}; /// Storing indegree of each node


 while(m--)  // m is number of edges
 {
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);  // this means there is an edge from 'a' to 'b'. a-->b
    outdegree[a]++;
    indegree[b]++;
 }
 int sink;  
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
    if((outdegree[i]==0 )&& (indegree[i]==(n-1)))
        sink=i;
 }
 cout<<"Sink/Pit is: "<<sink<<endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

Am I missing something? Don't search the graph following graph edges. Just iterate over all n vertices in the graph and test each one for the number of incoming and outgoing edges. I assume for each vertex you can store a count of incoming and outgoing edges. This would scale O(n), if you have the edge counts.

@REPLY: We'd have to know how your graph is implemented to get more specific. But I mean something like:

```
foreach( node in graph )
     if (( node.numberInputEdges == numNodes -1 ) && 
         ( node.numberOutputEdges == 0 ))
         print ( "this node is a pit" )
```

Comment: could you explain something more , plz ?

Comment: this will give o(n^2) if adjacency matrix is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a adjacency list implementation , just scan it,and you will find in O(n) time,if there is a vertex with outdegree 0.
If you have a adjacency matrix, you can use DFS.

In DFS , just just increment the counter indegree whenver we find a outgoing node.

A pseudo code :

```
for each adjacent node :
   indegree->neighbour ++;
   if (neighbour not visited ) dfs(neighbour)
```

Finaly scan indegree array to get which node has indegree (n-1) ,bcoz every node will have an edge to the Pit .

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one "pit" in a graph (because of the deg_in = N-1). So search for all nodes with deg_out = 0. If two, stop. If one, check the deg_in. This is O(N).